# pandas/dataframe: removing duplicate rows based on the multiple unique values in single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe want to remove duplicates of the column on the basis of another column.
In example I'm just using the 2 column and three values but in 'a' column the values 35 and instead of b there are multiple columns. How can I do it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]
df['b'] = [34,34,35,35,35,23,23,23,35,35,89,89,89,78,78]
```

remove the rows where column 'b' value is 35 and removing 2 from 'a'.
May be I don't able to articulate the question but attaching screenshot of my expected output

[image]

Comment: Use: `out = df[df['a'].ne(2) | df['b'].ne(35)]`

Comment: I think respondents misread intent of question.

Comment: it seems to be asking how to delete 35 from group 2, becuz 35 exists in group 1.

Comment: @mozway there are multiple values in a not only 2 but there are multiple values

Comment: it is not a group.. just added sample dataset to show what i want..

Comment: @Sushil Kokil I understand your intentions, so if you create a new question, I'll answer it.

Comment: @PandaKim : should I delete this question ? or change the title of the question

Comment: im newbie only Member for 9 days. can you remake question? then remake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249630/discussion-between-sushil-kokil-and-panda-kim).